# In Ionic4 how to refresh detail view to get updated record after put call in edit view and navigating back to detail page

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I am making a simple crud with Ionic4, everything is working fine. When i update my record via put call and navigate back to detail of the record to see updated values it shows old values. My update and navigate code is:

```
async updateClient() {
  await this.api.updateClient(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'), this.clientForm.value)
  .subscribe(res => {
      let id = res['_id'];
      this.router.navigate(['/client/detail', id]);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And detail page code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RestApiService } from '../../rest-api.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {
  client: any = {};
  constructor(public api: RestApiService,
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
    private location: Location) {}
    async getClient() {
        console.log('in getClient');
        const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
        });
        await loading.present();
        await this.api.getClientById(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.client = res;
            loading.dismiss();
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            loading.dismiss();
        });
    }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClient();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `this.getClient()` method in `ionViewWillEnter()` method as below :

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.getClient();
}
```

It will call your `this.getClient()` method every time when you enter in the page whether it is loaded or not.

Comment: Great! Perfect Thank you